# Laravel 4 URL::action not working as intended

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having some problems with laravel 4 route reversing. 
Basically I have a restful controller that needs reversing. There's very little information on the internet about how to do it, and the existing ones all talk about laravel 3(and very vague). I checked them out, they propose "Case 1" in the following code, which didn't work. After a lot guessing and struggling I found out "Case 2" works. Why is Case 1 not working? How should I get it to work?

FooController.php

```
class FooController extends BaseController{
  public function getHello(){
    return View::make("bar");
  }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::controller("foo","FooController ");
```

bar.blade.php

```
{{URL::action('foo@hello')}}//Case 1: This doesn't work

{{URL::action('FooController@getHello')}}//Case 2: This works
```

Comment: Because when you call action, you need to specify the full controller name and full action name. If you define Route::controller, and type foo/admin-profile in the address bar, it will automatically respond to `FooController@getAdminProfile`. By the way you can use `Route::resource` to get named restful routes around a resource `foo` http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lead to same controller/action after all...

```
// routes.php
Route::get('foo/hello', 'as' => 'foo.hello', 'uses' => 'FooController@getHello');

// Somewhere in your view, etc.



{{ URL::to('foo/hello') }}

{{ URL::action('FooController@getHello') }}

{{ URL::route('foo.hello') }}
```

Comment: Good answer! I think that Xun is wondering why does he have to specify the verb (GET) in the action even he has declared the controller as restful in routes.php. My belief is that declaring `Route::resource('Foo')` is the best approach in this case because it will bring named routes and restful actions altogether.

Comment: Yeah, resource controllers are my best choice after all, totaly agree with you!

Comment: OK thanks! Still I don't know why the tutorials don't work, but I guess I can live with the verbs. The "magic" prefix stuff in laravel(or PHP?) is driving me nuts btw... And I think laravel do needs better tutorials.

Comment: Sometimes tuts are not so straightforward, sometime you need to look at source code as well. Got spare $9? Try https://laracasts.com/ for a month, will teach you a lot! Or go to Tuts+ for starter https://tutsplus.com/?s=laravel&post_type=all

Comment: {{ URL::to('foo/hello') }} solved my problem. Thank you